# Ideas from the future changing the past

Tags: technology, alternate-history, time-travel

There is a thesis that I rather support, claiming that most inventions where done when done not because of lack of creativity, but because the technology or society were not ready for them. But I might be wrong.

Let's see, how a technology from today might change WW2. Let's limit the personal influence and siphoning back historical knowledge. We do technology.

So, we have an option to dump a sea container full of books on a particular topic in front of a major government building in the capital of any of the Allies' country on the 1st of September 1938. Be it in front of the Pentagon or at [Lubyanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubyanka_Square).

**Books on what topic do you put inside the container?**

(I have some ideas, will put my own answer below. But I am interested in unconventional answers.)

Comment: This is a cool question but I fear there is no way to objectively answer it.

Comment: What outcome are you trying to achieve? To stop WWII? To shorten it? To reduce casualties? To change how Europe was divided after the war? I also think that considering how different the roles of the USA and the USSR were, it would be better to ask 2 different questions each focusing on one country.

Comment: with a _whole container_ full - do you really have to select that much? you can sufficiently cover most wartime-relevant topics, and many more. you can change it however you like.

Comment: @Otkin: I did not want to limit the goals. Pick any part of the Allies (we do not do the baddies here) and help them in a way you want to. I'd say the goal is the maximal change. I am not taking the usual _issekai_ route of a person time-traveling, but of information being made available. One might argue that nothing would change a bit, as people then were not dumber than now. Basically, they already used all the technology they could produce. New ideas would not help. Or would they?

Comment: This is too broad for the WB.SE. Here questions should be more specific. There is a rule for questions about events that states that the questioner needs to provide 2 out of 3: Starting conditions, end conditions (result), and process. You are asking an interesting question (and I disagree with the opinion-based reason, I VTC'ed as needs more details and clarity), however, it does not comply with the existing rules. May I suggest asking a series of questions exploring different scenarios and outcomes? I think you would still be able to get some good answers while complying with the WB.SE rules

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered deception? Scholarly-looking books on some utter B.S.?

I know you said Ally countries; but maybe instead the Reich Chancellary under construction in Berlin at Hitler's direction in 1938. The Nazi headquarters. You dump this container of books on magic, the methods of Nostradamus, anti-gravity, the transmutation of elements, it contains plausible-looking (for 1938) instructions for a seemingly magical technology that require an utterly rare element with 164 protons, a stable super-heavy element produced in a supernova and found in only one remote place on Earth; the result of an meteor fall 138 million years ago, from another star system.

**Hitler believed in magic.** All the technology attributable to element-164 is magical, a "portal" element, just a grain of it let Nostradamus see the future in his magic bowl. It supports remote viewing, it supports sending objects into the future or past; so they seem to magically disappear or magically appear. It promised to hand Hitler the power to easily spy on his enemies without detection, to manipulate the past, to take over the world! And he falls for it, instead of fighting the war with armies, he devotes all the resources of Germany to searching this underwater mountain range in Antarctica or something, trying to find the vague source of this fictional element-164, which of course totally does not exist.

WWII is derailed by Hitler on this wild goose chase, seeking the easy way out, a super weapon that makes him the ultimate hero with virtually no casualties. It channels his insanity in a truly pointless and mostly harmless direction.

Comment: Wow, that's a nice twist! Pretty much an anti-thesis of what I though, but might work as well. I would be wary of telling Nazis of element-164, as they might as well find elements 92 and 94 in progress and that would not be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple options:

- Books on **signal processing** would help with radars and such. However, they won't be able to build fancy DSPs or compute large-size [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) outside from computers, occupying full buildings for quite a long time. Forget putting something on a plane. A ship, maybe, but British are doing it anyway already without us.
- Books on history of **cryptography**, on actual cryptography, and on computers as such would help cracking [Enigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine), similar Japanese cyphers, might help to develop own cyphers that are more secure. The problem: Most of those things today are based on digital computers, which is not going to happen soon enough. But some novel ideas and principles might be transferrable to mechanical, Enigma-like devices. Where they smart enough to develop them without us? Unsure.
- Books on **medicine** seem like a no-brainer, but it appears that aside from [antibiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_penicillin) and some anti-inflamation drugs there is little that can be propagated to the fighting army on a short-term notice. New methods for external fixation would help a lot of people to lead a better life after the war, but that's a bit of a different story.
- Books on **nuclear physics** that would help to cut corners in [Manhattan project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project) (or it counterpart). Duh. I think it'll count as forbidden, as it is too obvious.
- Perhaps the most impactful after books on nukes would be books on **optimization theory**. Because [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) is simple enough to be done by hand, and a lot of logistics is simply the transport problem. However, people pretty much everywhere are already working on it or will be soon: [Leontiev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassily_Leontief), [Dantzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dantzig), [Kantorovich](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87,_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). As the area was already developing, the gap to bridge is minimal and the effect is large.

Two obvious and forbidden choices are:

- Books on **military history** where all the successful and unsuccessful operations of the war are listed. It might be possible to send books on military tactics as such, but I doubt that there are many of them that do not study pervious operations, including the WW2.
- Books on **history** in general, including the later course of the politics after the war, whereabouts of Axis' dictators during the war (useful for covert operations), etc.